# Is there a way to put a description on a SQL Server permission itself?

Tags: sql-server

It would be nice if I could put a description on a permission itself, e.g. "This insert permission is granted on this table because application foo needs it in order to bar."  Is there a way to do this?  Or of not, where would I go to suggest it to the SQL Server team?

Comment: If you are granting permissions in the table create or alter scripts you should be able to add a comment using -- Description of permissions here.  Put that right above where you grant the permissions.

Comment: There is currently no way to store a description like that within SQL Server outside of having your own table for it and aligning that table with the permission and changes.  If you take the approach @Brad mentions then you could store that in source control and then have history.

Comment: Although you can't create meta-data on the permission itself, you can use [extended properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addextendedproperty-transact-sql) to attach a description of the permission to the table.